# Apache mod_rewrite add trailing slash with aliases

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force a trailing slash in a URI using rewrite engine.

```
http://www.mysite.it/test -> http://www.mysite.it/test/
```

This is my configuration:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ http://www.mysite.it/$1/ [L,R=302]
 #this is an .htaccess config
```

This works only for the server name "www.mysite".
How to generalize it to follow also server aliases?

```
http://www.mysite.it/test -> http://www.mysite.it/test/
http://www.myalias.it/test -> http://www.myalias.it/test/
http://www.anotheralias.it/test -> http://www.anotheralias.it/test/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable for picking host name from the request:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [NE,L,R=302]
```

PS: `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`